# Integer for Id rather than GUID when using ASP.NET Identity w/ a custom data store

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am aware that when using ASP.NET Identity w/ Entity Framework you would do the following to tell Identity that the User class will be using an int instead of a GUID for Id

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int>
```

However, since I am not using EntityFramework my class declaration is like this:

```
public class User : IIdentity
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
    public virtual String PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public string NormalizedUserName { get; internal set; }
    public string AuthenticationType { get; set; }
    public bool IsAuthenticated { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Can I change the Guid to an int without running into issues or do I have to implement IdentityUser still? IdentityUser is part of the Identity.EntityFramework package which is no longer installed in my application.

Comment: how far along are you in your app?

you can probably convert it to an Int, but you might start breaking other things that depend on the Id being a guid or string.  you might have a lot of casting to do.

if you cannot convert to an Int, can you leave it as a string and box your int inside?  its yukky, i know, but ...

Comment: I'm sure it can be done, but is it worth the effort? If there are no real advantages and it isn't a requirement then I should leave it as it is. However, I would change Guid to String. Asp.Net Identity uses nvarchar(128) for the id. This gives the advantage that you can override the Id with any value, including an int value (as string). I don't expect issues with converting Id to int, but you'll have to make sure that everything that touches the identityuser can handle the changed id type.